# How to draw lines through Bootstrap vertical dividers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap
I need to draw menu line this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hl8moeabxxecu8j/dropdown.png .

So I need draw lines through vertical dividers.

Here what I have now - http://jsfiddle.net/KckU3/8/

I can't get how to make it ?

Comment: The dropbox link is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you had a typo in the `.dropdown-toggle` class.

Then, you are not looking for a vertical divider, which would look like a border, but for a border, and you just need to hide some of it.

Here is your clue :

```css
.navbar .nav > li > a.dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
    z-index: 1005;
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    /* ... */
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The `padding-bottom` is actually just one more pixel than defined by default.

The other important thing is the position to left or right :

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {  
    /* ... */
    left: 0px;
}
```

I fixed a few other things for better effects, but you have the main idea.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/KckU3/10/)

Comment: @DenMed I don't understand, you'll have to be more specific. And maybe its not related to this question.

Comment: @Sherbow, I mean to draw border-top only for dropdown-toggle.

Comment: @DenMed I still don't see what you want. If my answer correspond to your question, accept it. If not, you should provide more information in your original question post : images, what you wish to achieve, the problems you encounter.

Answer (score 22):

simply use

```
<hr class="divider">
```

that should give you what you want

Answer (score 4):

Now there is:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
```

Comment: "now" might look odd in time - perhaps you could qualify it (e.g. is this for HTML 5 and above?)

Comment: this is the shortest and best answer!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly

```
<li><hr></li>
```

Should be useful

Comment: Sorry, I understood you wrong. I would make images for menu items. It would be easiest way to do it I think

Comment: It is not programming solution and I don't draw well.

Comment: Its not programming solution but its solution. Easy solution. Its up to you use it or not. I just suggested

Comment: So you suggest to draw three pictures : 1. without hover a link
2. hover first link
3. hover second link 
yes ?

Comment: Actually yes. 1.without hover, 2.hover without drop down (if needed), 3. hover with drop down

Answer (score 0):

Your post is somewhat confusing, but from the image you posted, it appears you want to create a tabbed menu with a dropdown? If so, Bootstrap already lets you do that.

Tab Menus: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs
Dropdowns: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Here's a demo that puts it together: http://jsfiddle.net/LWTqS/

Comment: Thanks, but this image is not fully correct, it show just idea what I need to do.

Comment: thanks.one more question: how I can draw a border ONLY over dropdown-toggle ?

Comment: you're going to have to add some custom CSS to override Bootstrap's default styles for tabs and dropdown-menus. I suggest using Chrome's developer tools to inspect what rules are being applied to the elements you want to change so you can know where to start